# Error With Insertion Sort

Tags: java, sorting, insertion-sort

**My insertionSort Program not showing the correct result :'(**

Arry is    : 5 2 6 1 3

Result will: 1 2 3 5 6

But not Showing Result.

Code is:

```
public class insertionSort
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int data[] ={5,2,6,1,3};
        for(int j = 2; j <data.length; j++)
        {
            int key = data[j];
            int i = j - 1;
            while(i > 0 && data[i] > key)
            {
                data[i + 1] = data[i];
                i=i-1;
            }

            data[i + 1] = key;
            System.out.print(data[j]+" ");


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a perfect opportunity to use your IDE's debugger and step into the code to see why it's not doing what you expect. It's a necessary skill.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 public class insertionSort
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int data[] ={5,2,6,1,3};
    for(int j = 1; j <data.length; j++)
    {
        int key = data[j];
        int i = j - 1;
        while(i >= 0 && data[i] > key)
        {
            data[i + 1] = data[i];
            i=i-1;
        }

        data[i + 1] = key;


       System.out.print(data[j]+" ");
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

Start the main `for-loop` with **`j = 1`**, and make the condition in the while loop **`i>=0`**

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class insertionSort {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int data[] = { 5, 2, 6, 1, 3 };
        for (int j = 1; j < data.length; j++) {
            int key = data[j];
            int i = j - 1;
            while (i >= 0 && data[i] > key) {
                data[i + 1] = data[i];
                i = i - 1;
            }

            data[i + 1] = key;

        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data));
        // It prints [1, 2, 3, 5, 6]
    }
}
```

Comment: You must start it from `j=1` to make an iteration over the first element in the array

Comment: @user2779836 mmm ... What does `tq` means? :D

Answer (score 0):

You can create separate class for this issue.
And really on this class this objectiv.

Like this one:

```
public class InsertionSorter {
    private int[] a;

    /**
     * Constructs an insertion sorter.
     * @param anArray the array to sort
     */
    public InsertionSorter(int[] anArray) {
        a = anArray;
    }

    /**
     * Sorts the array managed by this insertion sorter
     */
    public void sort() {
        for (int i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {
            int next = a[i];

            // Move all larger elements up
            int j = i;
            while (j > 0 && a[j - 1] > next) {
                a[j] = a[j - 1];
                j--;
            }

            // Insert the element
            a[j] = next;
        }
    }
}
```

Or use only static method with array argument for existing class.

Answer (score 0):

Among other things, it looks like the prrimary problem here is that you're trying to print out the elements of the array **while** you're sorting it.  Let's take a look at a couple iterations of your loop to see what's happening:

```
j = 2; data = { 5, 2, 6, 1, 3 }
    key = data[2] = 6
    i = j - 1 ==> i = 2 - 1 = 1
    data[i] = 2 < key = 6 <-- while loop does nothing
    data[i+1] = data[2] = key = 6
    data[j] = 6

j = 3; data = { 5, 2, 6, 1, 3 }
    key = data[2] = 1
    i = j - 1 ==> i = 3 - 1 = 2
    data[i] = 6 > key = 1
        data[3] = data[2] ==> data[3] = 6
        i = i - 1 ==> i = 1
    data[i] = 2 > key = 1
        data[2] = data[1] ==> data[2] = 2
        i = i - 1 ==> i = 0
    i <= 0 <-- while loop stops
    data[i+1] = data[0] = key = 1
    data[j] = 6

data = { 5, 1, 2, 6, 3 }
```

In English what's happening is the insertion sort is keeping the maximum element (6) at your loop index j, because that's how insertion sort works.  So each loop iteration you simply print out the current maximum element of the list, which in this case is always 6.  You also start your outer loop at the wrong index (you should start at 1, not 2, why did you start at 2?).  You're also not letting your inner loop look at the first element of the array.

So your code should look more like this:

```java
public class insertionSort
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        int data[] = { 5, 2, 6, 1, 3 };
        for( int j = 1; j < data.length; ++j )
        {
            int key = data[j];
            int i = j - 1;
            while( i >= 0 && data[i] > key )
            {
                data[i + 1] = data[i];
                --i;
            }

            data[i + 1] = key;
        }

        for( int k = 0; k < data.length; ++k )
        {
            System.out.print( data[k] + " " );
        }
    }
}
```